# QPID Connection factory properties

Tags: apache-camel, jms, amqp, qpid, spring-camel

My system is based on camel and use [Apache QPID 0.37.0](https://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-jms-0.37.0/docs/index.html) to consume messages from a remote AMQPS sever. Our system authenticates via a client certificate. Thus I have this piece of configuration:

```
<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg name="remoteURI" value="amqps://some-location:5671?transport.keyStoreLocation=/very/long/path/nnn-openssl.p12&amp;transport.keyStorePassword=*******&amp;transport.trustStoreLocation=/very/long/path/server.keystore&amp;transport.trustStorePassword=*******"/>
</bean>
```

This is just working fine. However, configuring key/trust store this way (i.e. in the URI) has several drawbacks:

- First, it is not easy to read and maintain.
- Some components log the URI, so the paths (I can live with it) and the passwords (ouch...) get logged.

I know it's possible to configure via a system property (`javax.net.ssl.keyStore`, and son on), but it's not an option because different modules may use different key and trust store, and we want to keep them in separate files.

Is there a way to configure those transport properties of **JmsConnectionFactory** in a different way ?

Something like:

```
<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg name="remoteURI" value="amqps://some-location:5671"/>
    <property name="transport.keyStoreLocation" value="/very/long/path/nnn-openssl.p12"/>
    ...
</bean>
```

Note that this factory is used in a JMSConfig, which in turn is used within an AMQPComponent:

```
<bean id="jmsConfig" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration" >
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
    ...
</bean>

<bean id="amqp" class="org.apache.camel.component.amqp.AMQPComponent">
    <property name="testConnectionOnStartup" value="true"/>
    <property name="configuration" ref="jmsConfig" />
    ...
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, that's all that class supports.  However you could write a configuration bean which has the properties you require, and have that create the bean.  Off the top of my head, something like this:

```
@Configuration
public class QpidConfiguration {

    // Add setters for these
    private String host;
    private int port = 5671;
    private String keyStore;
    private String keyStorePassword;
    private String trustStoreLocation;
    private String trustStorePassword;

    @Bean
    public JmsConnectionFactory createConnectionFactory() {
        return new JmsConnectionFactory("amqps://" + host" + ":" + port + "?transport.keyStoreLocation=" + keyStoreLocation + "&transport.keyStorePassword=" + keyStorePassword + "&transport.trustStoreLocation=" + trustStoreLocation + "&transport.trustStorePassword=" + trustStorePassword);
    }
}
```

You probably want to add some parameter validation in there to be safe.

You can then define the bean using more convenient properties.

```
<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="com.example.QpidConfiguration">
    <property name="host" value="some-location"/>
    <property name="keyStoreLocation" value="/very/long/path/nnn-openssl.p12"/>
    ...
</bean>
```

You can also leverage encrypted property placeholders, if your heart so desires.

Comment: It's an interesting solution, but it does not fully meet my needs: I still end up with an ugly-and-very-long remoteURI containing my paths and passwords. And that URI is logged in JMSConnection. Upvoted anyway.